# Nvidia video settings on Ubuntu get reset back to 1024x768 when logging back in

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, gnome, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

In [making changes to video settings in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/65437/cant-make-changes-to-video-settings-in-ubuntu/65452#65452) I tried the following in Gnome:

```
gksudo nvidia-settings
```

Resolution is set to 1920x1080 and applied, voila screen looks fine.
`/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is saved, great.

So far so good.

But on the next login it reverts back to 1024x768. I don't get it. What is the problem?

Running Ubuntu 8.04, NVIDIA Driver Version: 173.14.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should really upgrade both system and/or vga driver.

Second, just use `sudo nvidia-xconfig`. So the official config utility writes the xorg.conf, all clean, all good.

Reboot, and execute this: `sudo nvidia-settings`. Set resolution there and click Save to X Configuration File. That's all.

(I'd stay far from such things like the one you mentioned.)

Answer (score 2):

Mission accomplished, it was so trivial.

> System > Preferences > Screen Resolution Apply & Keep Settings.